# jquery, json and success function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have written this code, but I am not able to make it works as it should..:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.a_mod', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var id =  $(this).attr('rel');
        var var_id = '<?php echo $id ?>';
        var data_3 = 'id=' + id + '&var_id=' + var_id;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: data_3,
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "php/show_tariffa.php",
            success: function(html){
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(html);
                $.each(obj,function(index, element){

                var id = element.id;
                var prestazione = element.prestazione;
                var prezzo = element.prezzo;
                var check = element.prezzo_mult;

                $('#id_tariffa').val(id);
                $('#nome_2').val(prestazione);
                $('#prezzo_2').val(prezzo);
                }); // fine .each

                $('#box_2').slideUp();
                $('#box_3').slideDown().css({"border-color": "#F31041"},'fast');
                } // fine success
            }); // fine ajax
    });
});
</script>
```

Using Firefox and firebug I can see that the event starts and that the php script is executed but, I don't know why, the "success:" part of the ajax doesn't start at all..

Here there is the php script:

```
<?php

    include("connect.php");

    $id = $_POST['id'];                 // id
    $var_id = $_POST['var_id'];         // id_dentista

    $html = array();

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT
                            tariffe.id,
                            tariffe.prestazione,
                            tariffe.prezzo,
                            tariffe.prezzo_mult
                            FROM tariffe
                            WHERE tariffe.id_dentista = '$var_id' AND tariffe.id = '$id'")
                            or die(mysql_error());

    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $html[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($html);

?>
```

What's wrong? what am I missing?

Thanks Davide,

Comment: The most likely cause is that the ajax request was unsuccessful, or, the data returned didn't match the dataType you were expecting. You should use error callbacks in ajax requests so that you can see **why** they failed.

Comment: if I had to guess you are not returning any data try console logging your html

Comment: Don't pass user input directly into your query. This will get you injected. You could cast it as an int or use mysql_real_string_escape.

Comment: I think that scripts stops at die(mysql_error()); returns string, string is not json and ajax fails. var_dump() your query string and mysql result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

After hours of troubleshooting in chatroom, I finally just installed this code on my server and set up the database.  It works fine,  the only issue was a BOM signature at the beginning of every file.

You need to set the encoding of your files to UTF8,  not UTF8 BOM and you should be good.   My guess is there is a BOM signature at the beginning of the returned data which is making $.parseJSON() mad.

Let me know if that fixes it, if not, it's back to the old drawing board.

---

If you are sure your query is successful,  then add an error callback to your script *(or use the delegate script below and its already added)*.

This should give you the reason why your script is erroring out.

```
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    console.log(status);
    console.log(error);
    console.dir(xhr);

}
```

Also, I'm not sure about FF, but in Chrome, you can go to the Network tab and click on your ajax script.  You can then view the data being sent, and the response.   You are probably having an issue with datatype/contenttype.

[image]

[image]

Sidenote:

You should be delegating your AJAX calls to properly handle event bubbling.

You should also be validating your input and not accessing superglobal $_POST directly.

You should also not use PHP inside of JS.  Instead create an element in your HTML and replace this ...

```
var var_id = '<?php echo $id ?>';
```

with this ...

*HTML*

```
<input id="hiddenId" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

*jQuery*

```
var var_id = $("#hiddenId").val();
```

### Delegate Ajax

```
(function($){
    $(function(){


        //Usage Example

        var inputString = $("#myInput").val();
        var inputNumber = $("#myInteger").val();
        var data = {inputString: inputString, inputNumber : inputNumber};

        $('parent').on('click', 'button', delegateAjax('js/myAjax.php', data, 'POST');

    });

    function delegateAjax(url, data, responseType, dataType, callback) {

        function successHandler() {
            console.log("Ajax Success");
        };

        function failureHandler(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log("Ajax Error");
            console.log(status);
            console.log(error);
            console.dir(xhr);
        };

        function handler404(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log("404 Error");
            console.log(status);
            console.log(error);
            console.dir(xhr);
        };

        function handler500(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log("500 Error");
            console.log(status);
            console.log(error);
            console.dir(xhr); 
        };

        url = typeof url !== 'undefined' ? url : 'js/ajaxDefault.php';
        data = typeof data !== 'undefined' ? data : new Object();
        responseType = typeof responseType !== 'undefined' ? responseType : 'GET';
        dataType = typeof dataType !== 'undefined' ? dataType : 'json';
        callback = typeof callback !== 'undefined' ? callback : 'callback';

        var jqxhr = $.ajax({url: url, type: responseType, cache: true, data: data, dataType: dataType, jsonp: callback, 
                            statusCode: { 404: handler404, 500: handler500 }});
        jqxhr.done(successHandler);
        jqxhr.fail(failureHandler);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

### Correctly Validate/Sanitize Input

```
$args = array(
    'inputString' => array(
        'filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
        'flags' => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR
    ),
    'inputNumber' => array(
        'filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
        'flags' => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR
    ),
    'inputNumber2' => array(
        'filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
        'flags' => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR
    )
);
$post = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $args);
if ($post) {


        $response = array('status' => 'success');
        echo json_encode($response); exit;
}
```

Comment: thanks for all the replies...

I modified the script adding the error function and using the "hiddenId" and than get the value with Jquery as suggested!

Ok with the error function I get an error and it is probably as you said about the json.. Here is the error:

parsererror
prezzi.php (riga 206)
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
 

...SON.parse(b+"");var c,d=null,e=m.trim(b+"");return e&&!m.trim(e.replace(xc,funct...

Comment: Yeah, it's most likely getting an error message from your script, which is not JSON, so it's not able parse it.   Can you use the provided screenshots to check your dev tools and find out what the program is actually sending back.   OR you can use  console.dir(html) before the parseJSON line and it should show up in your console. @P.Davide

Comment: ok that's what I get :

{"4":[],"5":{"0":"265","id":"265","1":"apparecchio","prestazione":"apparecchio","2":"200.00","prezzo"
:"200.00","3":"0","prezzo_mult":"0"}}  

and I added the console.dir(html) before var obj = JSON.parse(html);

But I am a little bit confused.. I added the following line in my php script:

echo json_encode($html); is it right?

Comment: Your PHP looks fine...   Are your ID's that are being queried against integers or varchars?   Your using single quotes, you should remove those if they are of type INT.    Can you print_r($row) inside your fetch loop and post the results in your question?  I want to see what the data is looking like in PHP.

Comment: Actually, can you go to this chatroom?  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82235/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-31191247-jquery-json-and-success-function-3119

Comment: That's what I get:

Array
(
    [0] => 261
    [id] => 261
    [1] => pulizia generale
    [prestazione] => pulizia generale
    [2] => 50.00
    [prezzo] => 50.00
    [3] => 0
    [prezzo_mult] => 0
)
{"4":[],"5":{"0":"261","id":"261","1":"pulizia generale","prestazione":"pulizia generale","2":"50.00"
,"prezzo":"50.00","3":"0","prezzo_mult":"0"}}

Comment: Thanks!! everything is fine! :-)